# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined - Google app script

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code that gets dates and saves them and an array so that it's used in another function to make a POST request. I am having a challenge passing these dates into a post requestand keep getting an error Cannot read property '0' of undefined. I will appreciate help with this.

Dates code:

```
function getDate(){

 var dateArray = [];
 var date1= new Date(2021,2,15);
 var date2 = new Date(2021,3,15);

 Set the current date to the starting date 
 var date = date1; 
 
 while(date<=date2){

   dateArray.push(date);
   date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
 }

 return(dateArray);
}


function user_assignments()
{
  var user = getUsers()

  var assign_arr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < user.length; i++)
  {
    var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/' + user[i].ID + '/assignments?auth=' + tkft_token + '&from=' + start + '&to=' + end
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var info = JSON.parse(response);
    var content = info.data;


    if (content.length > 0)
    {
      for (var j = 0; j < content.length; j++)
      {
        var rec = {}
        rec.user_id = content[j].user_id
        rec.assignable_id = content[j].assignable_id
//        rec.ends_at = content[j].ends_at
        assign_arr.push(rec)

      }
    }


  }

  return assign_arr;
}
```

POST Request code:

```
function clear_demo(date)
{
var user_dt = user_assignments()
var usedates = getDate()

for (var i = 0; i < user_dt.length; i++)
  {

     var data = {

      'hours': 0,
      'date': usedates[i],//Having challenge here
      'user_id': user_dt[i].user_id,
      'assignable_id': user_dt[i].assignable_id,
    };
    var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
    var options = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'payload': data,
    };
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, for example, when you modified `'Content-Type': 'application/json',` to `'contentType': 'application/json',` and also, `'payload': data,` to `'payload': payload,`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @Tanaikethanks for looking at this. Actually, the challenge here is passing getting date array into the 'function clear_demo'. I have called the date function using 'var usedates = getDate()' but not able to pass it to 'var data' I hope I am making sense?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your script, I thought that `dateArray.push(date)` might be required to be modified. Because in this case, I'm worry that the value is the call by reference. So please modify `dateArray.push(date)` to `dateArray.push(new Date(date))`. By this, the dates from Mar 15 2021 to Apr 15 2021 are put to the array. I thought that this might be the answer for your current question.

Comment: But I'm not sure about the API you want to use. So I'm not sure whether your request is correct and `'date': usedates[i],` can be directly used. So if this modification didn't bring your goal, can you provide the detail information about the API you want to use? By this, I would like to modify it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on dates. Now, I would like to loop through the dates in 'dateArray.push(new Date(date))' and pass them in the line ''date': usedates[i]'. how do I do this?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your script, what is `var user_dt = user_assignments()`? If the indexes of `user_dt` are the same with `usedates`, your script can be used. But I have no information about `var user_dt = user_assignments()`. I apologize for this.

Comment: I have edited my question with the script for 'var user_dt = user_assignments()'. Please look at it. Also, the indexes of 'usedates' and 'user_dt' are not the same

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your updated question, I cannot still understand about your goal. I apologize for my poor understanding. You want to give all dates of `usedates` for each `user_dt`? In this case, the request is run in 2 loops. Or, you want to achieve other direction?

Comment: You are correct. I need to assign 'usedates' for each 'user_dt' how do I do that ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have some worries. In your script, the values of `usedates` are the date object. So when `'date': usedates[j],` is used, the date object is directly put. In this case, your API can use this? Even when the loop process was modified, I'm worry that an error might occur by the specification of API. Or, in your question, you want to modify only the loop process rather than the work of request? I'm worry whether I could correctly understand about your question. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Just does the answer below not solve your issue? Also, be aware that you method of creating an array of dates is returning an array of references to the same date object. If you want different date objects you need to use the `new` keyword.

Comment: @iansedano, the answer below did not solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the object *data*, not the JSON *payload* for the options.

```js
    var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
    var options = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'payload': payload, // was 'data'
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer quite yet, but will edit based on your feedback. Posting this here because the explanation is too long for the comments.

I have experimented with your code and adapted this small snippet to test if `usedates[i]` works.

```js
function getDate() {
  var dateArray = [];
  var date1 = new Date(2021, 2, 15);
  var date2 = new Date(2021, 3, 15);

  var date = date1;

  while (date <= date2) {
    dateArray.push(date);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }

  return dateArray;
}

function clear_demo(date) {
  var usedates = getDate();

  for (var i = 0; i < usedates.length; i++) {
    var data = {
      date: usedates[i]
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
}

clear_demo();
```

This works without error and gives this result on the console:

```
{"date":"2021-04-15T22:00:00.000Z"}
```

This identical result, 32 times.

The reason its identical is that every time you `dateArray.push(date);` you are just pushing a reference to the same date object. You would need to change this to `dateArray.push(new Date(date.getTime()));`.

Yet that is not the problem you are facing. You are saying that this code returns the error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` on the line `date: usedates[i]` - but that is not giving me any errors. Are you sure it fails on this line? Might it not be because `user_dt[i]` fails for some reason?

What does `assign_arr` log at the end of `user_assignments()`?